# angular multi-select drop-down without bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

Does anybody have created or used any multi-select drop-down using angular without bootstrap?

Using dropdown I should be able to select multiple items using checkbox.

I see there are some examples available but they all work in conjunction with bootstrap. I cant use in my project as we have our own custom css.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen or https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen and there are more available if you do a search.

Comment: checked the links u have given. This is little different than my expectation. I will need to select multiple items at once using checkbox.